# Webdav access to /var/www

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, webdav

I am trying to set up webdav to the /var/www directory on debian 8.4

I can setup webdav to access a subdirectory of /var/www such as /var/www/webdav but when I remove the directive from the apache conf file it doesn't seem to work. for example:

```
    Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav

    <Directory /var/www/webdav>
        DAV On
    </Directory>
```

if this is

```
    Alias /webdav /var/www

    <Directory /var/www>
        DAV On
    </Directory>
```

I get an error:

```
cadaver http://192.168.200.85/webdav
Could not access /webdav/ (not WebDAV-enabled?):
Did not find a collection resource.
Connection to `192.168.200.85' closed.
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Please check your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file (or the one corresponding to the virtual host in question).

Comment: There's probably a `<directory /var/www>` somewhere else in your config file (since it's the root) which doesn't include the `DAV on` directive.  You should modify that one, not add another one.

Comment: even when adding "DAV On" to the <directory /var/www> i still get: root@computer:/# cadaver http://192.168.200.85/
Could not access / (not WebDAV-enabled?):
405 Method Not Allowed
Connection to `192.168.200.85' closed.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, I setup a symlink for the folder that is accessed via webdav.